# get data from amazon kinesis into java web application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, extract, amazon-kinesis

I am new to amazon kinesis so might be this question is very basic question.
But i need help on this,
I am having one use case where i need to pull the data from amazon kinesis into my web application which has been created in JAva, i need to obtain the connection between the kinesis and java so that i can take the data from amazon kinesis and do some of the analytics on the data and if the data is modified then i need to put the data back to amazon kinesis from java application.
here my java application is not on the amazon clould, it is on my private cloud. so how do i do the above task.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Amazon Kinesis API endpoints are on public IP addresses, so you don't need to have EC2 instances within AWS environment to access Kinesis.

To read data from Kinesis, you can use Amazon's own Kinesis Client Library (KCL). 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client

On AwsLabs GitHub, there are also sample applications written in Java.
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors/tree/master/src/main/samples

About your architecture; if you want to process raw data and create meaningful extracts, I recommend you do some ETL tasks (aka: post processing) and write your results to another place (ie. RDBMS). On the view layer (your web app) you can display the resulting output in any format you like by reading from your database.